# Java Spring AOP: Using CustomizableTraceInterceptor with JavaConfig @EnableAspectJAutoProxy, not XML <aop:advisor>

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Spring AOP has a method-level tracer called `CustomizableTraceInterceptor`. Using Spring's XML configuration approach, one would set up this tracer like so:

```
<bean id="customizableTraceInterceptor" class="
  org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor">
  <property name="enterMessage" value="Entering $[methodName]($[arguments])"/>
  <property name="exitMessage" value="Leaving $[methodName](): $[returnValue]"/>
</bean>

<aop:config>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor"
    pointcut="execution(public * org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository+.*(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

I would like to set up above configuration using Spring's JavaConfig style (i.e. taking advantage of Java annotations, especially `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` for activating AspectJ in JavaConfig).

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "some.package" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "some.package2", "some.package3" })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class FacebookDomainConfiguration {

    @Bean someBean() {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

What is the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`-style equivalent for `<aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor" ...>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot because the Java language does not support method literals which would be needed to support this in Spring JavaConfig. A bug was opened for this but marked as "Won't Fix": https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8148.

The two options mentioned in the bug report are:

1. Continue using `<aop:config>` by including the relevant XML snippet using `@ImportResource`
2. Convert any existing `<aop:config>` elemements to use `@Aspect` style. *[which is not possible with the `CustomizableTraceInterceptor`]*

Answer (score 29):

I do it this way :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class TraceLoggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomizableTraceInterceptor customizableTraceInterceptor() {
        CustomizableTraceInterceptor customizableTraceInterceptor = new CustomizableTraceInterceptor();
        customizableTraceInterceptor.setUseDynamicLogger(true);
        customizableTraceInterceptor.setEnterMessage("Entering $[methodName]($[arguments])");
        customizableTraceInterceptor.setExitMessage("Leaving  $[methodName](), returned $[returnValue]");
        return customizableTraceInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Advisor jpaRepositoryAdvisor() {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("execution(public * org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository+.*(..))");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, customizableTraceInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Comment: I use this code above but the `CustomizableTraceInterceptor` seems not triggered

Answer (score 17):

Just wanted to add to AdrienC's response.
I'll use the point expression to reference an aggregated point, more clearer separation, imho

```
package org.example;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Aspect
public class AopConfiguration {
    /** Pointcut for execution of methods on {@link Service} annotation */
    @Pointcut("execution(public * (@org.springframework.stereotype.Service org.example..*).*(..))")
    public void serviceAnnotation() { }

    /** Pointcut for execution of methods on {@link Repository} annotation */
    @Pointcut("execution(public * (@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository org.example..*).*(..))")
    public void repositoryAnnotation() {}

    /** Pointcut for execution of methods on {@link JpaRepository} interfaces */
    @Pointcut("execution(public * org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository+.*(..))")
    public void jpaRepository() {}

    @Pointcut("serviceAnnotation() || repositoryAnnotation() || jpaRepository()")
    public void performanceMonitor() {}

    @Bean
    public PerformanceMonitorInterceptor performanceMonitorInterceptor() {
        return new PerformanceMonitorInterceptor(true);
    }

    @Bean
    public Advisor performanceMonitorAdvisor() {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("org.example.AopConfiguration.performanceMonitor()");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, performanceMonitorInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Comment: In my humble opinion, this should be marked as the correct answer, just verified with Spring 4. :)

Comment: Thank you men! I was searching exactly this solution since morning!))